# UML: How show an object using itself in a method

Tags: java, oop, uml

```
class Player {
    public void printOpponent(Player opponent) {
    // ...
    }
}
```

How would the UML representation of Player look like considering one of its methods requires an object of type Player?

Comment: The same way you would represent it if it required an `int` or any other type.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the diagram.

The **class diagram** shows classes and the relation between then.  It could look like:

[image]

You could in theory show the dependency to the argument type, because the class needs to know the argument type to use it:

[image]

But this would be overkill: the dependency is related to classes and not individual objects; and a class always depends implicitly on itself.

The **sequence diagram** would show how objects of the different types interact. To show how the operation on one object `p1` is called with `p2` as argument,  you'd need to show the objects involved:

[image]

Or you could show a simpler scenario, such as:

[image]

These two diagrams only show that `printOponnent()` is called with another player as argument.  But perhaps you want to enrich them to show some implementation details afterwards, e.g. what messages are exchanged between p1 and p2 in the context of `printOpponent()`